# How to exclude quote in alphanumeric string

Tags: php, regex, replace

This is the example string:

```
User.status <> 'actived'
```

I want this:

```
`User`.`status` <> 'actived'
```

But with the following regex:

```
/([a-z_]+[a-z0-9_]+)/i
```

The result is:

```
`User`.`status` <> '`actived`'
```

A context code usage:

```
protected function escapeExpression($expression)
{
    //$expression = "User.status <> 'actived'";
    //escapeKeyword returns '`' . $param . '`'
    return preg_replace('/([a-z_]+[a-z0-9_]+)/i', $this->escapeKeyword('$1'), $expression); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to escape some SQL code.  Can you provide more context as to what you need this for?

Comment: It is part of a library I'm developing.
Is specific to a QueryBuilder.

Comment: @CristianGonzales If you need to add clarification (or especially code), it is better suited for an edit to your question than a comment. Just click the edit link to the left of your badge at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(?<!['a-z0-9_])([a-z_]+[a-z0-9_]+)(?!['a-z0-9_])/i` would do the trick, using a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead.

Comment: With that regex the result is: \`User\`.\`status\` <> 'a\`ctive\`d'